# Bring VTK files to the web?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vtk

Does anyone know how I can bring VTK files (3D rendered grafics) into the web/browser? With support for drag-drop and zooming? Maybe there is already an existing lib that I did not find?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not had a chance to look at this in depth and it may not be what you want, but I came across this a while back while looking up some visualisation techniques.

I believe this may do what you want although I have not looked at the API and how you would go about implementing it, it does however look like it is pretty wrell documented.

Link to [ParaViewWeb](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaViewWeb)

Link to [demo](http://paraviewweb.kitware.com/PWStates/run.jsp?id=1)

Comment: The link to 'demo' is broken.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into XTK: https://github.com/xtk/X#readme - I haven't used it myself, but it looks nice.